# AngularJS : use local storage when offline

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angularjs, callback, q

I'm using AngularJS and I'd like to know how to use local storage data when offline. I've tried this in my service :

```
ProjectList = $resource("json/home");
var projectList = ProjectList.query(function(data) {
                localStorage.setObj("key", data); 
                },
                 function(){
                  return localStorage.getObj("key");
                });
return projectList;
```

This is not working, data are cached but there's no binding when I turn off tomcat. So i've done something like this :

```
   var projectList  = $q.defer();
        var list = ProjectList.query(function() {

          projectList.resolve(list);

        },
            function(){
                projectList.reject(list);
            });
        return projectList.promise;
```

And in controller

```
       ProjectService.getProjectsList()).then(function(data){
                console.log("DATA = " + data);
                localStorage.setObj('listCacheKey', data);
                $scope.projets = data;
       },
            function(){
                 $scope.projets = localStorage.getObj('listCacheKey');
          });
```

which is working but i don't understand why the first one don't. Can someone explain it ?